# MATLAB - How to replace the first NaN in each column with zero?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, nan

I have a series of columns with positive values and then NaNs, for example:

```
12    16    10
11    13    9
8     10    7 
7     6     5
4     1     4
2     NaN   2
NaN   NaN   1
NaN   NaN   NaN
```

If this matrix is `A`, then the (row) position of the first NaN in each column can be found using: `sum(~isnan(A))`

I would now like to replace the NaNs in each of these locations with a zero, for example:

```
12    16    10
11    13    9
8     10    7 
7     6     5
4     1     4
2     0     2
0     NaN   1
NaN   NaN   0
```

So far, my attempts using combinations of logicals, indices and loop approaches have failed, creating a new matrix with all NaNs as zeros, all values in each found row as zeros, or the NaN in only the first or last column as a zero.

What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

```
[m,n] = size(A) %// get size of input data
[v,ind] = max(isnan(A))  %// positions of first nans in each column
ind2 = bsxfun(@plus,ind,[0:n-1]*m)  %// linear indices of those positions
A(ind2(v))=0 %// set values of all those positions to zero
```

Code run on a sample input (slightly different than the one in question for a better demo) -

```
A (Input) =
    12    16    10
    11    13     9
     8    10     7
     7     6     5
     4     1     4
     2   NaN     2
     4   NaN     1
     1   NaN   NaN


A (Output) =
    12    16    10
    11    13     9
     8    10     7
     7     6     5
     4     1     4
     2     0     2
     4   NaN     1
     1   NaN     0
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you would like to use your `sum(~isnan(A)` code, that could form another approach, but please note that this assumes that there are no numeric values once NaN elements start appearing in a column  and as such approach #1 is a safer one. Here's the code for approach #2 -

```
[m,n] = size(A); %// get size of input data
ind = sum(~isnan(A))+1; %// positions of first nans in each column
v = ind<=m; %// position of valid ind values
ind2 = bsxfun(@plus,ind,[0:n-1]*m);  %// linear indices of those positions
A(ind2(v))=0 %// set values of all those positions to zero
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer! You've only left me `acccumarray` :-)

Answer (score 5):

Divakar's solution works well, but as an alternate solution, you could use two nested `cumsum` to get a mask with the first NaN per row, and use it to reset those values to 0;

```
A =    
    12    16    10
    11    13     9
     8    10     7
     7     6     5
     4     1     4
     2   NaN     2
   NaN     7     1
   NaN   NaN   NaN

>>> A(cumsum(cumsum(isnan(A))) == 1) = 0

A =

    12    16    10
    11    13     9
     8    10     7
     7     6     5
     4     1     4
     2     0     2
     0     7     1
   NaN   NaN     0
```

Comment: Good smart one-liner +1! But as pointed out in the other solution in approach #2, if there are numeric values after one or more NaN elements in a column, it won't produce the desired results.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for pointing that out, there should be restrictions on using matlab before first morning coffee :)

Comment: There are always restrictions! From the amount of caffeine in the morning coffee to the number of sleeping pills at night ;)

Answer (score 2):

Approach based on [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[ii jj] = find(isnan(A)); %// rows and columns of NaNs
ind = accumarray(jj,ii, [], @min); %// minimum row for each column with NaNs
ind = ind(ind~=0); %// a 0 indicates no NaNs in that column, so it should be removed
A(size(A,1)*(unique(jj)-1)+ind) = 0; %// set those entries to 0 using linear indexing
```

For example,

```
A = [ 12    16    10
      11    13     9
       8    10     7
       7     6     5
       4     1     4
       2   NaN     2
       4   NaN   NaN
       1     5   NaN ]
```

is transformed into

```
A = 
    12    16    10
    11    13     9
     8    10     7
     7     6     5
     4     1     4
     2     0     2
     4   NaN     0
     1     5   NaN
```